# In Ruby, using "net/http", we have to join the url and query using a "?" ourselves?

Tags: ruby

In the following code, we have to join the `url.path` and `url.query` ourselves using the `?` character?  Is there a more elegant way to do it?   I have to use `net/http` because in some situations I want to put a string in the header for the user-agent as well.

```
require 'net/http'

url_string = 'http://www.time.gov/timezone.cgi?Pacific/d/-8'

url = URI.parse(url_string)

response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.get(url.path + '?' + url.query)
end
puts response.body[/<td.*(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/, 1]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `request_uri` method on the URI object:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/HTTP.html#M009499

Updated version of your code:

```
require 'net/http'

url_string = 'http://www.time.gov/timezone.cgi?Pacific/d/-8'

url = URI.parse(url_string)

response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.get(url.request_uri)
end
puts response.body[/<td.*(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/, 1]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`URI#request_uri`](http://santoro.tk/mirror/ruby-core/classes/URI/HTTP.html#M004904)

From the docs:

> Returns the full path for an HTTP
>   request, as required by
>   Net::HTTP::Get.
>
> If the URI contains a query, the full
>   path is URI#path + ’?’ + URI#query.
>   Otherwise, the path is simply
>   URI#path.

Answer (score 3):

Net/http may make a good foundation but it's not very user-friendly.

If your client is accessing a well-designed service, then something like [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html), [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client), or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) will be a better choice. You could also write an application-independent module that civilizes net/http in a way that works well for you.